# is possible to use graphql with couchdb?

Tags: couchdb

I work well with graphql environment, and I need to use couchdb, but his api with uris like rest api, it's for me a little old way to retrive data. Is possible to use graphql with Couchdb ?  or there are plans in the future ?

Answer (score 3):

I think GraphQL is a tool meant to smooth the way for you to write the custom API for your own app. Very few databases have a commonly published API as yet.

Some people have started playing with GraphQL for couchdb and pouchdb - see these repos on Github

- https://github.com/chentsulin/awesome-graphql
- https://github.com/esnet/couchdb-graphql-test
- https://github.com/robertkowalski/couchdb-graphql
- https://github.com/MikeBild/graphql-pouch

Comment: those packages was not updated 1 years ago or more.. looking for some another solution

Comment: To your posted question, the listed projects demonstrate that the answer is "Yes". If you are looking for a supported product, that should be your question.

Comment: the answer with your links it's no, because they are old packacges impossible to use with graphql updated

Comment: There is an blogpost on using couched with GraphQL you can check if that helps.  https://blog.couchbase.com/creating-a-graphql-application-with-node-js-and-a-nosql-database/